# Deploy Provider Hosted App

Tags: sharepoint-addin, deployment, provider-hosted-app

I have tried deploy hosted app but always appear error message like "Error  1

> Error occurred in deployment step 'Install app for SharePoint': The
>   provided App differs from another App with the same version and
>   product ID.       0   0   Hosted.App "

Why the error always appear? I  have tried with a long and short way to build an hosted app.

Can you help me or give me 1 reference to build a hosted app that can help me

Answer (score 1):

The problem with you is very simple.

Your app already exists in App Catalog of your site. Just delete that app from App Catalog and make sure it should be deleted from both level Recycle Bin. And try again installing the App.

Another Approach for you:

[SharePoint 2013 Apps: The provided App differs from another App with the same version and product ID](http://www.jeremythake.com/2013/10/sharepoint-2013-apps-the-provided-app-differs-from-another-app-with-the-same-version-and-product-id/)

Step By Step Details for creating a provider hosted app can be found [here](http://www.sharepointpals.com/post/Step-by-Step-approach-to-create-a-Provider-Hosted-Application-in-SharePoint-2013)

Answer (score 1):

I too have faced this issue once.
How I resolved it:

1. Remove the app from all site collections
2. Remove the app from the second stage recycle bin
3. Remove the app from the app catalog site
4. Change the version number of the app and the product id from appmanifest.xml as in below screenshot and then upload the app again.

[image]